# PHP is printing outside of HTML

Tags: php, html, output

I have a html page with php embedded inside which looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
function printTable(){
echo '<table></table>';
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
printTable();
?>
```

when executed the html output is

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<table></table>
```

I want the table to be printed inside de DIV element. How can i do that?

Comment: What should be the gain of creating function, creating any string inside and the calling this function? You can write down the HTML without this function.

Comment: you are echoing it outside the div.Get rid of the function and echo it inside the div

Comment: Seriously @panther? Better to post pages and pages of code than a simple example?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: it doesn't matter how long is the code inside this function. Code like `function xy(){...} xy();` is non-sense.

Comment: @panther, and if the code does a sql query?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: it isn't obvious from the question. Just a speculation.

Comment: @panther, no worries, but I would not want a first time poster to get the wrong impression. Better to post a 'simple' example than tons of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
function printTable(){
echo '<table></table>';
}
printTable();
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have a function that generates output, the output will be generated where that function is **called**, not where it is **defined**. You're calling it ***after*** the closing `</html>` tag, so it will be echoed at that point

Comment: Oh I understand, when I put the php code on top it printed the table on top of the html.. 

Thanks for the reply

I am going to try something else..

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling your function after the  tag. It should be called within your div block,ie

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
function printTable(){
echo '<table></table>';
}
printTable();
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
function printTable(){
echo '<table></table>';
}
printTable();
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, we call `printTable()` function inside the `<div>`. So, Table will be printed in the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function printTable(){
  return '<table></table>';
}
?>
<html>
 <body> 
 <div>
  <?php echo printTable(); ?>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably you should give the OP a minimal explanation how PHP (Hypertext **Preprocessor**) works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<?php
function printTable(){
  return '<table></table>';
}
?>
<html>
 <body> 
 <div>
  <?php echo printTable(); ?>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Or this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
function printTable(){
echo '<table></table>';
}
printTable();
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```